Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception 2 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with info or-debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

enter image description here
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with info or-debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

